# Select the correct input when using input group after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Introduction**: I'm creating a form using bootstrap and I have different input groups with the same structure and functionality.

All of them have a '-' button on the left and a '+' button on the right of the input field and, when one of them is pressed, the input value has to change.

**Problem**: As the buttons are inside a div with class="input-group-btn" and they are not siblings of the input field, I don't know which is the best way to select it.

I have managed to make it work but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it.

**JavaScript and HTML**

```js
$(".increase").click(function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parents('.input-group').children('input').val());
  if (amount < 20) {
    $(this).parents('.input-group').children('input').val(amount + 1);
  }
});


$(".decrease").click(function() {
  var amount = parseInt($(this).parents('.input-group').children('input').val());
  if (amount > 0) {
    $(this).parents('.input-group').children('input').val(amount - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrease"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capacity" value="0" disabled="">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default increase"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrease"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rooms" value="0" disabled="">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default increase"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/EA5a48SCdg

Answer (score 1):

If the input group perhaps contains additional input elements this won't work. I think that you should bind the button to the input field by declaring a new attribute to the button which is connected to the input's `id`. Like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default increase" data-bind="rooms"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

It now contains the input ID which this button is connected to. Now in your JavaScript try something like this:

```
$(".increase").click(function() {
  var input = $('#' + $(this).data('bind'));
  input.val(input.val++);
});
```

It will use the data-bind attribute to connect to the specific input element and increase this value by 1 (++).